# Changing .cs file code but it is not really changing

Tags: c#, .net, telerik

I am changing code in a .cs file, but in the frontend it is not changing, this .net project is built with the help of Telerik Framework, this is the source code side script, that i am trying to change, but its not changing for me in the frontend.

Contact.aspx

```
<%@ Page language="c#" Codebehind="Contact.aspx.cs" AutoEventWireup="True"  MasterPageFile="~/DP.Master" Inherits="divorce.Contact" %> <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentLeft" runat="server"> <h3>Contact Us</h3>
        <table cellSpacing="8" cellPadding="0" width="730" border="0">
            <tr>
                <td vAlign="top" align="left">
                    <blockquote>
                        <div class="body">Feel 
                                free to browse around this site. If you have comments or questions about our 
                                services, or simply need more information and want to contact us, click on the 
                                contact button on any page within this site.<br>
                                <br>
                                We promptly respond to all inquiries.</div>
                            <DIV id="lblError" style="DISPLAY: inline; WIDTH: 363px; COLOR: red; FONT-STYLE: italic; FONT-FAMILY: Arial; HEIGHT: 17px"
                                ms_positioning="FlowLayout" runat="server">Label</DIV>
                            <p></p>
                                <table cellSpacing="0" cellPadding="5" width="79%" border="0">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td vAlign="top" width="25%">
                                            <div align="right"><font face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="1">Your 
                                                    Name:</font></div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td width="64%">
                                            <div align="left"><input id="contactName" type="text" size="50" name="ContactName" runat="server"></div>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td vAlign="top" width="25%">
                                            <div class="style8" align="right"><font face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="1">Your 
                                                    Email Address:</font></div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td width="64%">
                                            <div align="left"><input id="email" type="text" size="50" name="Email" runat="server"></div>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td vAlign="top" width="25%">
                                            <div class="style8" align="right"><font face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif" size="1">Comments:</font></div>
                                            <p class="style8" align="left" valign="texttop">&nbsp;</p>
                                            <p>&nbsp;</p>
                                        </td>
                                        <td width="64%">
                                            <div align="left"><textarea id="comments" name="Comments" rows="15" cols="38" runat="server"></textarea></div>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td vAlign="top" colSpan="2">
                                            <div align="center"><input id="contactSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit" name="contactSubmit"></div>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                    </blockquote>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table> </asp:Content>
```

Contact.aspx.cs

```
using Pobk.OpenMail.Message; 
using System; 
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel; 
using System.Data; 
using System.Drawing;
using System.Web; 
using System.Web.Mail; 
using System.Web.SessionState; 
using System.Web.UI; 
using System.Web.UI.WebControls; 
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;

namespace divorce 
{
    public partial class Contact : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            this.lblError.Visible = false;

            if (this.IsPostBack == true)
            {

                if (this.contactName.Value.Trim().Length == 0 ||
                    this.email.Value.Trim().Length == 0 ||
                    this.comments.Value.Trim().Length == 0)
                {
                    lblError.InnerText = "Please fill out all three fields - your name, email address, and message.";
                    lblError.Visible = true;
                }
                else if (IsValidEmail(this.email.Value) == false)
                {
                    lblError.InnerText = "Please enter a valid email address.  Example: MyName@MyServiceProvider.com.";
                    lblError.Visible = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
                    msg.From = "andrew@divorcepacket.com";
                    msg.To = "andrew@divorcepacket.com";
                    msg.Subject = "DivorcePacket Contract Form";
                    msg.Body = this.email.Value + " " + this.comments.Value;
                    msg.BodyFormat = MailFormat.Text;

                    try
                    {
                        SmtpMail.SmtpServer = @"relay-hosting.secureserver.net";
                        SmtpMail.Send(msg);
                        this.Response.Redirect("messagesent.aspx?s=y", false);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        this.Response.Redirect("messagesent.aspx?s=n", false);
                    }

                }

            }

        }

        private bool IsValidEmail(string strEmail)
        {

            try
            {
                return (new EmailAddress(strEmail)).IsValid;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return true;
            }

        }

        #region Web Form Designer generated code
        override protected void OnInit(EventArgs e)
        {
            //
            // CODEGEN: This call is required by the ASP.NET Web Form Designer.
            //
            InitializeComponent();
            base.OnInit(e);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {

        }
        #endregion
    }

}
```

Can anyone help me on this?

What the problem coming is, when i am trying to change the .cs file, it is not changing things on my aspx file, for example if i m trying to change the the code this.Response.Redirect("messagesent.aspx?s=n", false); to this.Response.Redirect("messagesent234343.aspx?s=n", false); it is not changing after form submission the form is going to the same old place i.e. messagesent.aspx?s=n and not to messagesent234343.aspx?s=n in short: i am doing the changes, but its not changing in the aspx file –

Comment: What is your expected results ?

Comment: We'd need more information. What do you mean by the "frontend"? If you're using some special package to help you write code, are your code changes actually making it into the file? We need to know if your changes aren't being saved to the code, or if the code isn't rendering what you're expecting.

Comment: What the problem coming is, when i am trying to change the .cs file, it is not changing things on my aspx file, for example if i m trying to change the the code 
this.Response.Redirect("messagesent.aspx?s=n", false);

to this.Response.Redirect("messagesent234343.aspx?s=n", false);

it is not changing after form submission the form is going to the same old place i.e. messagesent.aspx?s=n and not to messagesent234343.aspx?s=n


in short: i am doing the changes, but its not changing in the aspx file

Comment: Do you have the issue running locally or only when deployed to a server?  Did you try to do a "Rebuild" in Visual Studio instead of a "Build".  Have you tried clearing your browser cache or trying another browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds sort of like what happened to me yesterday. I eventually found out that my visual studio which hadn't been restarted in awhile was not actually saving the files even though it appeared to be rebuilding and running the code. A computer and visual studio restart got it working for me.